# How to close only the YesNoCancel Dialog Box on clicking Cancel Button,keeping the background project visible

Tags: c#, wpf, cancel-button

I have a dialog box with Yes, No and Cancel clicking Yes save the currently created project, On clicking the Cancel button should just close the Dialog box doing no action.

```
private void closeproject_click(DialogResult DResult)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the project and close tool? 
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) ==  DialogResult.Yes))
    {
        //Save the current Project if not saved and close 
    }
    else if("Do you want to save the project and close tool? 
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) ==  DialogResult.No))
    {
        //doesn't save the project and get closes
    }
    else if("Do you want to save the project and close tool? 
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) ==  DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // should close the dialog box form only 
        // what do i write
    }
```

Complete Tool should not get closed, only the dialog should close on clicking the Cancel Button and kill the background process.

Comment: You want in third else-if condition that project should save and message box should close ? only message box should close not the whole project ?

Comment: why don't you use simple wpf approach  `MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("My Message Question", "My Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // Do this
            }`

Comment: No, on clicking the Cancel button, should just do nothing, meaning just close the dialog box. The issue I am facing is if I click Cancel Complete Tool (Main Window) is closing.

Comment: check my answer. i hope it will help :)

Comment: Clicking _Cancel_ will definitely close the dialog only. I looks like your application is crashing. First enable exception breaking of the debugger. To do so got to the menu: Debug/ Windows/ Exception Settings and tick at least "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Then start your application in debug mode to see where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple approach to perform what you are trying to do.

```
private void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("My Message Question", "My Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        //Saveproject(); // write your save code here or call saving method and close the whole project
        Close();
    }
    else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        Close(); // dont do anything just close project
    }
    else if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
        // you dont even need this third condition on cancel btn click only message box will close 
        //and nothing else will happen  
       // additionally you can use here
          e.Cancel = true;  
          e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Done with the first two conditions, the third condition is creating the problem, clicking cancel btn- message Box isn't getting closed instead it's closing the entire application. Anyway thanks for your early response:)

Comment: it's not possible because i have tried this code ! debug your code and see what lines are executing after the third condition ! i guess after close_projectCLick event some other line is executing that is closing your app !

Comment: or you may put `e.Cancel = true;` or `e.Handled = true;` in third condition ! this will work im sure !

Comment: @DGS if it worked you should accept this as answer .Stay blessed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do nothing, just write nothing in that condition. Let the event simply return, then it does nothing.